# Angular2 - how to catch exception on rxjs map() function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular2 service that calls a server which I expect to return an object. Upon error, the server returns an HTML Error web page.
I want to capture when that web page is being returned, instead of an object, so that apply `json()` method on the response, in the `map()` function, which will result as an error.

I've tried using a try-catch block in the `map()` section:

```
getServerObject(objId: string) : Observable<ServerObject> {
  const url = environment.serverURL + '?objId=' + objId;
  return this.http.get(url)
       .map( res => {
         try {
           res.json();
         } catch(err) {
            console.error('ERROR: ' + err);
         }
       } )
       .catch(this.handleServerError);
}
```

Unfortunately, excecution never reaches the `catch` block, even though the  `res.json();` fails.

What can I do to catch this case?

Comment: you should remove try catch in map , and you can try use `Observable.throw(err)` in `handleServerError`function

Comment: I can see it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/PZoNBjhilQk0xWl6M3yv?p=preview

Comment: @Ibrahim Thanks! that works